# Store MATLAB 3d viewport

Tags: matlab, plot

I am using MATLAB to display 3d data. I use the GUI to change to view angle, zoom and pan. How can I store this view and later apply it to another figure (containing more or less the same data)? `view` gives me a matrix, but how can I apply this to another figure?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the current view angle on another figure, you could do:

```
% call when the source axes is the current axes
[az, el] = view; 
% call when the target axes is the current axes
view (az, el);
```

Or, you could do the same using `get` and `set` of the `view` property.

However, to apply all the view properties you mentioned together, it is easier to use Matlab's built-in 'generate m file' option - when you have the 3D figure the way you want it, go to `file`->`Generate m-file`, and an m-file will be created that gets the 3D data as an input, and apply the settings.

Another option is to save these relevant settings yourself (just inspect the m-file generated):

```
plot3(sin(t),cos(t),t);
pba = get(gca, 'PlotBoxAspectRatio');
dar = get(gca, 'DataAspectRatio');
cva = get(gca, 'CameraViewAngle');
cuv = get(gca, 'CameraUpVector');
ct = get(gca, 'CameraTarget');
cp = get(gca, 'CameraPosition');
```

and then to apply it to the current axes (assuming the target axes is the current one):

```
set(gca, 'PlotBoxAspectRatio',pba);
set(gca, 'DataAspectRatio',dar);
set(gca, 'CameraViewAngle',cva);
set(gca, 'CameraUpVector',cuv);
set(gca, 'CameraTarget',ct);
set(gca, 'CameraPosition',cp);
```

Answer (score 2):

To store and apply view see [Itamar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090195/store-matlab-3d-viewport/5090943#5090943).

For zoom and pan you just need to store axes limits. Use xlim, ylim and zlim or corresponding axes properties (XLim, etc.) with get/set.

For current axes to store limits:

```
xl = xlim;
yl = ylim;
zl = zlim;
```

Or with axes properties:

```
xl = get(gca,'XLim');
```

To apply to axes on another figure:

```
xlim(new_axes_handle,xl) % you can skip new_axes_handle for current axes
ylim(new_axes_handle,yl)
zlim(new_axes_handle,zl)
```

Or

```
set(new_axes_handle,'XLim',xl,'YLim',yl','ZLim',zl)
```

---

By the way, in addition to Itamar's answer, you can get all axes properties at once into a structure:

```
ax_properties = get(gca);
```

Remove the fields you don't want to apply to the new axes, then use SET:

```
set(new_axes_handle,ax_properties)
```

Be careful since the structure will contain UserData as well. Remove this field first. You can do it by the code:

```
rmfield(ax_properties,'UserData')
```

Answer (score 1):

OMG, manual adjustment and the generate M-File option is my hero. If only I knew from the beginning that all I had to do was this:

```
axes1 = axes('Parent',Plot_ele,'PlotBoxAspectRatio',[1 1.70454545454545 1.7],...
    'DataAspectRatio',[1 1 1],...
    'CameraViewAngle',7.48227189414101,...
    'CameraUpVector',[-0.0256575066196788 0.989185543639328 -0.144407938178721],...
    'CameraTarget',[255.013054349713 397.874703616223 449.003273637903],...
    'CameraPosition',[1445.8877301745 1407.25270740567 7151.59363497921]);
    % xlim(axes1,[0 528]); % uncomment to preserve axes x-limits
    % zlim(axes1,[0 897.6]); % uncomment to preserve axes z-limits
hold(axes1,'all');
```